# Kafka stream does not retry on deserialisation error

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-retry

Spring cloud Kafka stream does not retry upon deserialization error even after specific configuration. The expectation is, it should retry based on the configured retry policy and at the end push the failed message to DLQ.

Configuration as below.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input_topic.consumer.maxAttempts=7
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input_topic.consumer.backOffInitialInterval=500
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input_topic.consumer.backOffMultiplier=10.0
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input_topic.consumer.backOffMaxInterval=100000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.iinput_topic.consumer.defaultRetryable=true
```

```
public interface MyStreams {

    String INPUT_TOPIC = "input_topic";
    String INPUT_TOPIC2 = "input_topic2";
    String ERROR = "apperror";
    String OUTPUT = "output";

    @Input(INPUT_TOPIC)
    KStream<String, InObject> inboundTopic();

    @Input(INPUT_TOPIC2)
    KStream<Object, InObject> inboundTOPIC2();

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    KStream<Object, outObject> outbound();

    @Output(ERROR)
    MessageChannel outboundError();
}

@StreamListener(MyStreams.INPUT_TOPIC)
    @SendTo(MyStreams.OUTPUT)
    public KStream<Key, outObject> processSwft(KStream<Key, InObject> myStream) {
        return myStream.mapValues(this::transform);
    }
```

The metadataRetryOperations in KafkaTopicProvisioner.java is always null and hence it creates a new RetryTemplate in the `afterPropertiesSet()`.

```
public KafkaTopicProvisioner(KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties, KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        Assert.isTrue(kafkaProperties != null, "KafkaProperties cannot be null");
        this.adminClientProperties = kafkaProperties.buildAdminProperties();
        this.configurationProperties = kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties;
        this.normalalizeBootPropsWithBinder(this.adminClientProperties, kafkaProperties, kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties);
    }

    public void setMetadataRetryOperations(RetryOperations metadataRetryOperations) {
        this.metadataRetryOperations = metadataRetryOperations;
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        if (this.metadataRetryOperations == null) {
            RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
            SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
            simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(10);
            retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(simpleRetryPolicy);
            ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
            backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(100L);
            backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2.0D);
            backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(1000L);
            retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
            this.metadataRetryOperations = retryTemplate;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retry configuration only works with `MessageChannel`-based binders. With the KStream binder, Spring just helps with building the topology in a prescribed way, it's not involved with the message flow once the topology is built.

The next version of `spring-kafka` (used by the binder) has added the `RecoveringDeserializationExceptionHandler` ([commit here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/3953aa6b05904d6abf6b31511c30b8bf55582ce2)); while it can't help with retry, it can be used with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` send the record to a dead-letter topic.

You can use a `RetryTemplate` within your processors/transformers to retry specific operations.

Comment: There is minimal support for DLQ within the Kafka streams binder today, basically sending the failed record to a DLQ if it is configured. However, no retry mechanisms are provided as that's only applicable for message channel based binders. See this docs section for more details. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_error_handling

Comment: We will try to integrate with the `RecoveringDeserializationExceptionHandler` that Gary mentioned in the next version of the binder.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell and @sobychacko for clarification. I have configured `serdeError=sendtodlq` which is sending the deserialization failures to a DLQ. The intent here is to retry contacting schema registry if the failure is due to network issues. Can you please explain more around '**You can use a RetryTemplate within your processors/transformers to retry specific operations.**' ? because the only place i understood so far to handle deserialization failures with KStream binders is `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.deserialization.exception.handler`.

Comment: `RecoveringDeserializationExceptionHandler` would be really helpful to add more custom behaviours for these failures. Also, our requirement is to stop the kafka stream upon deserialization error then fix and reset the order of messages.

Comment: `>Can you please explain more around...` - that was for any errors in custom processors/transformers. To retry deserialization you can use a custom `Serde` to wrap the real `Serde` and use a `RetryTemplate` there.

Comment: I just added a `RetryingDeserializer` to spring-kafka; [PR here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1153).

Answer (score 0):

> Spring cloud Kafka stream does not retry upon deserialization error even after specific configuration.

The behavior you are seeing matches the default settings of Kafka Streams when it encounters a deserialization error.

From https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#handling-corrupted-records-and-deserialization-errors-poison-pill-records:

> `LogAndFailExceptionHandler` implements `DeserializationExceptionHandler` and is the default setting in Kafka Streams. It handles any encountered deserialization exceptions by logging the error and throwing a fatal error to stop your Streams application. If your application is configured to use `LogAndFailExceptionHandler`, then an instance of your application will fail-fast when it encounters a corrupted record by terminating itself.

I am not familiar with Spring's facade for Kafka Streams, but you probably need to configure the desired `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.DeserializationExceptionHandler`, instead of configuring retries (they are meant for a different purpose). Or, you may want to implement your own, custom handler (see link above for more information), and then configure Spring/KStreams to use it.